# ISC DHCP/DDNS setup: Static entries for non-dhcp clients

Tags: bind, internal-dns, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, ddns

I have set up a local network with ISC BIND9 and DHCP service. New leases trigger the DHCP to add an A and PTR record which works perfectly.

I also added lots of static host entries in the `dhcpd.conf`. Now I noticed that the DDNS update only works for clients that actually request a lease from the DHCP server. I have a few devices in the network that do not support DHCP. I still added static entries in the `dhcp.conf`. For those, no lease is requested and now no DNS-records are created. What options do I have to add those static entries in a way that DNS-records get created?

I would prefer to only use the `dhcpd.conf` if possible.
Greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I stumbled across this post when looking for info on another issue I have with ISC-DHCP and BIND9.*

If your devices aren't requesting DHCP leases then adding static entries to dhcpd.conf won't matter. If you've set a static IP on the devices itself, you'll need to add a DNS A record for those devices.

You'd do it like this:

```
sudo rndc freeze yourzone
sudo nano /etc/bind/db.yourzone
```

add your entry at the bottom like so

```
hostname         A          192.168.X.X
```

save and exit (but don't forget to increment the serial number at the top by one)

```
sudo rndc thaw yourzone
```

Maybe you've already fixed this yourself, but it might be helpful to someone else!

Do the same to the reverse lookup zone if you have one configured.

EDIT: Also make sure the static IP you set is not in the DHCP range, to avoid IP conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Add ddns-hostname to the static dhcp definition like so ...

```
host sark {
    hardware ethernet ....;
    fixed-address ....;
    ddns-hostname "sark";
}
```